# Newtonsoft Serializes Hidden Inherited Members

Tags: json, uwp

Using Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2 in a UWP project with class inheritance we want to be able to serialize the parent class without serializing the base class and we want to also be able to serialize the base class properties in other calls.  We redused the issue to a sample...

```
[DataContract]
public class Object1
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Property1
    {
        get { return "Property 1 data"; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Property2
    {
        get { return "Property 2 data"; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Property3
    {
        get { return "Property 3 data"; }
    }

}

[DataContract]
public class Object2 : Object1
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Property4
    {
        get { return "Property 4 data"; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Property5
    {
        get { return "Property 5 data"; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Property6
    {
        get { return "Property 6 data"; }
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public new string Property2
    {
        get { return "Property 2 data"; }
    }
}
```

Serialize Object...

```
Object2 myobject = new Object2();

string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myobject);
```

Result...

{"Property4":"Property 4 data","Property5":"Property 5 data","Property6":"Property 6 data","Property2":"Property 2 data","Property1":"Property 1 data","Property3":"Property 3 data"}

Property2 is serialized even though its set as hidden and/or ignored.

I would have expected that Serializing Object2 would not show Property2 because it is "hidden" using the new keyword and not set with DataMember and/or ignored specifically.

Comment: data member is ignored for this new overriden property but property is public in parent class, consider removing property2 totally ( even from baseclass ) and just put a "private string _property2" field in object1, with a "public string GetProperty2()" method which returns _property2, this can solve ur problem, and ur logic will remain the same.

Comment: Removing it or making it private doesn't solve the issue as we do want to be able to serialize the base class with that property.

Comment: System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractSerializer acts consistently with NewtonSoft in the same way pointed out above.  At least once I added setters to the objects.

Comment: @user3339251 Have you sloved your issue by adding setters to the objects?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT No, the point of the setters was in regard to comparing the behavior of System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractSerializer.  That library throws an exception if there are no setters.  Had to add setters (not included in original example) just to try that library.  System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractSerializer has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to XavierXie-MSFT for pointing out that I could not tell the difference of which object was serializing because the data was the same in both objects.  As I  expected the original example was serializing the property from the base class.  It wasn't an answer and only illustrated my point more clearly, but it did help me to analyze further.

In order to get the required behavior I had to make the base class Property2 virtual and override the property in the parent class.  In this scenario Property2 still serialized but from the parent class.  Then I changed to use the newtonsoft serialization ignore [JasonIgnore].  Then Property2 no longer serializes from either class when instantiated as Object2 type.

I would have expected hiding with new to have the same result.

I would have expected [IgnoreDataMember] to have ignored the overidden Property2 as [JsonIgnore] does.

I would have expected if there were no tag on Property2 in the parent class that the overridden Property2 would not have serialized.

Fortunately Virtualization and [JsonIgnore] do work.

solution:

```
[DataContract]
public class Object1
{
    public Object1()
    {
        Property1 = "property 1 data from object 1";
        Property2 = "property 2 data from object 1";
        Property3 = "property 3 data from object 1";
        Property0 = "should not be serialized from object 1";
    }

    public string Property0
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Property1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Property2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Property3
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}

[DataContract]
public class Object2 : Object1
{
    public Object2()
    {
        Property4 = "property 4 data from object 2";
        Property5 = "property 5 data from object 2";
        Property6 = "property 6 data from object 2";
        Property2 = "should not be serialized from object 2";
        Property7 = "should not be serialized from object 2";
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Property4
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Property5
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Property6
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// from parent class
    /// </summary>
    [JsonIgnore]
    public override string Property2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Property7
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}

Object2 myobject = new Object2();

string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myobject);

Object1 mybaseobject = new Object1();

string baseserialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mybaseobject);
```

Results:

serialized
{"Property4":"property 4 data from object 2","Property5":"property 5 data from object 2","Property6":"property 6 data from object 2","Property1":"property 1 data from object 1","Property3":"property 3 data from object 1"}

baseserialized
{"Property1":"property 1 data from object 1","Property2":"property 2 data from object 1","Property3":"property 3 data from object 1"}

Note: The C# UWP DataContractSerializer will still serialize Property2 from the parent class even when using [IgnoreDataMember].

Answer (score 0):

> Removing it or making it private doesn't solve the issue as we do want to be able to serialize the base class with that property.

If you do not want to serialize the `Property2` in object2, but still want to serialize the `Property2` in object1. Your original code should work. I believe you should be confused by the same value of the `Property2`. You could just change the value of `Property2` in object2 to distinguish.

```cs
[DataContract]
public class Object2 : Object1
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Property4
    {
        get { return "Property 4 data"; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Property5
    {
        get { return "Property 5 data"; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Property6
    {
        get { return "Property 6 data"; }
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public new string Property2
    {
        get { return "new Property 2 data"; }
    }
}
```

```cs
Object2 myobject = new Object2();
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myobject);
```

The result: `{"Property4":"Property 4 data","Property5":"Property 5 data","Property6":"Property 6 data","Property2":"Property 2 data","Property1":"Property 1 data","Property3":"Property 3 data"}`

You could see that it just serializes `Property2` in object1.

Comment: What you say is true and is my objection. The object is instantiated as Object2 type. Serializing it should not show hidden properties from Object1 as Object1.Property2 is hidden with the NEW keyword on Object2.Property2. The (Object2)myobject should not expose Object1.Property2 because of the new keyword. I always assumed it was Object1.Property2 that was serialized.  The same issue results if the property is virtual in the base class and overidden in the parent class.  I don't understand why the deserializer would even see these properties at all.

Comment: To be more clear when I say we still want to serialize the base class with Property2 I would expect the code to be: Object1 mybaseobject = new Object1();
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mybaseobject);  Because Object2 does not expose Property 2 from the base class.

Comment: I was wrong about the virtual property overridden in the parent.  When overriding as a virtual property the Property2 from Object2 is serialized even though it has [IgnoreDataMember].